# Is there something like the threading macro from Clojure in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming

In Clojure I can do something like this:

```
(-> path
      clojure.java.io/resource
      slurp
      read-string)
```

instead of doing this:

```
(read-string (slurp (clojure.java.io/resource path)))
```

This is called *threading* **in Clojure terminology** and helps getting rid of a lot of parentheses.

In Python if I try to use functional constructs like `map`, `any`, or `filter` I have to nest them to each other. Is there a construct in Python with which I can do something similar to threading (or piping) in Clojure?

I'm not looking for a fully featured version since there are no macros in Python, I just want to do away with a lot of parentheses when I'm doing functional programming in Python.

**Edit:** I ended up using [toolz](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/streaming-analytics.html) which supports `pipe`ing.

Comment: I thing you mean `List Comprehensions`. `threading` is a completely different  concept in python.

Comment: I suppose you could write a simple helper that would allow something like `thread(path, resource, slurp, read_string)`. If it doesn't already exist in `functools` or such.

Comment: that looks more like reverse piping than threading.  in any case, Python has no macros at all, let alone one do do what you describe.  OTOH it is possible to create your own if you define certain dunder methods. that's advanced stuff

Comment: In the context of Clojure, this is called threading (as in argument threading). It doesn't have anything to do with Threads. And it's more complicated than what deceze's suggestion would allow. The threading macro above inserts the threaded argument as the first argument of the other forms, in front of other arguments that were supplied. It doesn't simply take function references and do application.

Comment: If you are interested in FP in Python, have a look at [Toolz](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/)

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation of @deceze's idea (although, as @Carcigenicate points out, it is at best a partial solution):

```
import functools
def apply(x,f): return f(x)
def thread(*args):
    return functools.reduce(apply,args)
```

For example:

```
def f(x): return 2*x+1
def g(x): return x**2
thread(5,f,g) #evaluates to 121
```

Comment: That's cool, thanks. This definitely helps with the parentheses overload

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to take this to the extreme and do it all dynamically.

Basically, the below Chain class lets you chain functions together similar to Clojure's `->` and `->>` macros. It supports both threading into the first and last arguments.

Functions are resolved in this order:

1. Object method
2. Local defined variable
3. Built-in variable

The code:

```
class Chain(object):
    def __init__(self, value, index=0):
        self.value = value
        self.index = index
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        append_arg = True
        try:
            prop = getattr(self.value, item)
            append_arg = False
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                prop = locals()[item]
            except KeyError:
                prop = getattr(__builtins__, item)
        if callable(prop):
            def fn(*args, **kwargs):
                orig = list(args)
                if append_arg:
                    if self.index == -1:
                        orig.append(self.value)
                    else:
                        orig.insert(self.index, self.value)
                return Chain(prop(*orig, **kwargs), index=self.index)
            return fn
        else:
            return Chain(prop, index=self.index)
```

### Thread each result as first arg

```
file = Chain(__file__).open('r').readlines().value
```

### Thread each result as last arg

```
result = Chain(range(0, 100), index=-1).map(lambda x: x * x).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y).value
```