# Functional pipeline using python with advance operators

Tags: python, function, lambda, functional-programming

I am following the PyData talk in https://youtu.be/R1em4C0oXo8, the presenter whows a library for pipeling call `yamal`. This library is not open source. So, In my way of learning FP in `python`,  I tried to replicate the *basics* of that library.

In a nutshell, you build a series of *pure* functions in `python` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, etc) , and create a list of them as follows:

```
pipeline = [f1, f2, f3, f4]
```

Then, you can apply the function `run_pipeline`, and the result will be the composition:

```
f4(f3(f2(f1)))
```

The requirements to the functions are that all have one return value, and except `f1`, all have one input.

This part is easy to implement I had it done using a composing the functions.

```
def run_pipeline(pipeline):
    get_data, *rest_of_steps = steps
    def compose(x):
       for f in rest_of_steps:
          y = f(x)
          x = y
       return x

    data = get_data()
    return compose(data)
```

The talk show a more advance use of the this abstraction, he defines the "operators" `fork` and `reducer`. This "operators" allow to run pipelines as the following:

```
pipeline1 = [ f1, fork(f2, f3), f4 ]
```

which is equivalent to: `[ f4(f2(f1)), f4(f3(f1)) ]`

and

```
pipeline2 = [ f1, fork(f2, f3), f4, reducer(f5) ]
```

which is equivalent to `f5([f4(f3(f1)), f4(f2(f1))])`.

I try to resolve this using *functional programming*, but I simply can't. I don't know if `fork` and `reducer` are `decorators` (and if so How do I pass the list of following functions?) don't know if I should transform this list to a graph using objects? coroutines? (maybe all of this is nonsense) I simply utterly confused.

Could someone help me about how to frame this using `python` and *functional programming*?

*NOTE*: In the video he talks about observers or executors. for this exercise I don't care about them.

Comment: Super related. Almost a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50176529/3000206

Comment: Are you asking how to define `fork` and `reducer` ?

Comment: @user633183 yes.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I agree with you, related but not quite the same. Here I am asking for the `fork` and `reducer` implementation. If those are defined, maybe the answers given in the question that you mentioned could be applied.

Comment: This is a simpler version of your `run_pipeline` function, in case it's useful. http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/toolz/functoolz.html#pipes

Comment: Take a look at `fn.py` if you are interested in functional programming in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this library is intended to facilitate FP in Python, it's not clear whether the library itself should be *written* using lots of FP.

This is one way to implement using classes (based on the `list` type) to tell the `pipe` function whether it needs to fork or reduce, and whether it is dealing with a single data item or a list of items.

This makes some limited use of FP style techniques such as the recursive calls to `apply_func` (allowing multiple forks within a pipeline).

```
class Forked(list):
    """ Contains a list of data after forking """

class Fork(list):
    """ Contains a list of functions for forking """

class Reducer(object):
    """ Contains a function for reducing forked data """
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

def fork(*funcs):
    return Fork(funcs)

def reducer(func):
    """ Return a reducer form based on a function that accepts a
        Forked list as its first argument """
    return Reducer(func)   

def apply_func(data, func):
    """ Apply a function to data which may be forked """
    if isinstance(data, Forked):
        return Forked(apply_func(datum, func) for datum in data)
    else:
        return func(data)

def apply_form(data, form):
    """ Apply a pipeline form (which may be a function, fork, or reducer) 
        to the data """
    if callable(form):
        return apply_func(data, form)
    elif isinstance(form, Fork):
        return Forked(apply_func(data, func) for func in form)
    elif isinstance(form, Reducer):
        return form.func(data)

def pipe(data, *forms):
    """ Apply a pipeline of function forms to data """
    return reduce(apply_form, forms, data)
```

Examples of this in use:

```
def double(x): return x * 2
def inc(x): return x + 1
def dec(x): return x - 1
def mult(L): return L[0] * L[1]

print pipe(10, inc, double)    # 21
print pipe(10, fork(dec, inc), double)  # [18, 22]
print pipe(10, fork(dec, inc), double, reducer(mult))   # 396
```

EDIT: This can also be simplified a bit further by making `fork` a function that returns a function and `reducer` a class that creates objects mimicking a function. Then the separate `Fork` and `Reducer` classes are no longer needed.

```
class Forked(list):
    """ Contains a list of data after forking """

def fork(*funcs):
    """ Return a function that will take data and output a forked
    list of results of putting the data through several functions """
    def inner(data):
        return Forked(apply_form(data, func) for func in funcs)

    return inner

class reducer(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, data):
        return self.func(data)

def apply_form(data, form):
    """ Apply a function or reducer to data which may be forked """
    if isinstance(data, Forked) and not isinstance(form, reducer):
        return Forked(apply_form(datum, form) for datum in data)
    else:
        return form(data)

def pipe(data, *forms):
    """ Apply a pipeline of function forms to data """
    return reduce(apply_form, forms, data)
```